# User can access to only one directory with scp

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, file-permissions, scp

I want to create a user for my Ubuntu server. I will use this user to copy some files from server to my local computer. So permissions should be really limited. This user can only reach to **/some/path** directory in the server and read files. Nothing more.

To achieve this, I've created a user:

```
sudo useradd scp_user -M -d /some/path
sudo groupadd scp_group
sudo usermod scp_user -g scp_group
sudo usermod scp_user -s /bin/false  # disable ssh login
sudo chown -R scp_user:scp_group /some/path
```

And in my ssh config file:

```
Match Group scp_group
    ChrootDirectory %h
    #ForceCommand scp 
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

But getting an error:

```
scp scp_user@IP:/some/path/test.zip test.zip
scp_user@IP's password:
Could not chdir to home directory /some/path: No such file or directory
/bin/false: No such file or directory
```

Can you please tell me which step I'm missing?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/12181/how-do-i-create-a-user-with-read-only-access-over-ssh-to-a-limited-subtree-of-fo And the details are here:
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-ssh-env.en.html

Comment: scp requires a shell, but you have `/bin/false`.  SCP, unlike sftp, doesn't support a Chroot, or at least not with out a fair amount of work.

Comment: There are lots of examples of doing a sftp chroot that should work.  https://serverfault.com/search?q=ssh+chroot+sftp

Comment: @zoredache , so with same configuration can I use sftp instead of scp?

Comment: A chroot root with sftp is pretty easy, see the link.  The downside is that you have to  use the sftp client, instead of scp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a user with read only access over SSH to a limited subtree of folders?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12181/how-do-i-create-a-user-with-read-only-access-over-ssh-to-a-limited-subtree-of-fo)

Answer (score 0):

In your question there is various flaws, as already pointed out by others:

- The `ChrootDirectory` jails your user in his home directory
- In that directory, there is no `/bin/false` executable (nor `/bin/scp` that would be needed for the `scp` itself).

You can either:

- Copy `scp` binary and its required dynamically loaded libraries into the chroot (users home directory)
- Change the users shell back to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`
- Copy `bash` or `sh` binary and its required dynamically loaded libraries into the chroot (users home directory)
- (this is awful ...)

Or just use `sftp`:

- Specify `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` (and possibly `ForceCommand internal-sftp`) in the `sshd_config`
- Restart `sshd` server

You might also encounter some problems with permissions (read the errors in the server log!).